# UNIX timestamp of the last time an entry was edited

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

In Expression Engine the `{edit_date}` tag would not return a UNIX timestamp like `{entry_date}` does. To work around that I used the approach below.

Does any one have an idea of how this could be made easier?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="pieces" limit="1" track_views="three"}
<?php
$edit_date_string = {edit_date};
$edit_date = NULL;
if(!isset($edit_date_string)) {
  $edit_date = {entry_date};
} else {
  // Date format: 2011 05 25 00:53:44
  // Raw: 20110525005344
  $hour   = substr($edit_date_string, -6, 2);
  $minute = substr($edit_date_string, -4, 2);
  $second = substr($edit_date_string, -2, 2);
  $day    = substr($edit_date_string, -8, 2);
  $month  = substr($edit_date_string, -10, 2);
  $year   = substr($edit_date_string, -12, 2);
  $edit_date = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);
}
echo $edit_date;
?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

As a side note it seems this is an inconsistency which makes it harder to process and compare dates. There would probably be a good reason for it. Does anyone know? Thanks

Comment: Ask a question rather than ranting.

Comment: I edited back some of my opinions so it is now at the end. I understand why you changed it but I needed to keep my opinion in there for people who come after. I believe it is important that users get to say these kind of things because the information might get picked up by someone else who can react to it in order to make a change. I will be more intentional in how I phrase my questions from now on. Thanks :)

Comment: Questions are not the place for opinions.

Comment: I agree with that, but believe there is some room for it still. I have used Stackoverflow less than you but often see this happening with interesting discussions coming out of it. As long as people have a positive attitued (which you corrected me on) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got PHP 5.3, there's [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$edit_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $edit_date_string)->getTimestamp();
```

Or, even more directly, according to the [Expression Engine docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html):

```
$edit_date = {edit_date format="%U"}
```

Comment: Thanks! Clean, simple and very flexible :)

Comment: I was using `%u` instead and I got the wrong output. I was using that same documentation as reference but misread it. Thanks again!